# Sending notification with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with the following schema

```
UserId,notication_detail,notification_sent either 1 or 0
```

There would be many notifications for different users, like 10 notifications for `userId=10` or 4 notifications for `userId=3` (mean 4 different rows in table. There may be no notification for a particular UserId. What I want to do is to get Unsent notifications for all users separately and mail them. I can't use group by UserId here.
`select * from table where UserId="" and notification_sent=0`, this is the normal case for 1 user but I need to check it for different IDs of this table

Comment: can't you just call your working Select with different userids? or use `WHERE UserId = 123 OR UserId = 234 Or...`

Comment: @MMMagic each time the script runs the UserIds in the table would be different.. I mean there would be 1000 users in user table but only 10 UserIds in this table

Comment: hm not sure if i get what you try to achieve but if you just want to get all unsent notifications you could `SELECT nt.UserId,nt.notication_detail,nt.notification_sent FROM <notificationTable> AS nt INNER JOIN <userTable> AS ut ON nt.UserId = ut.UserId WHERE nt.notification_sent=0`

Comment: I don't understand your question... why would you supply a userId in the WHERE clause if you don't want to select a specific user?

Comment: You need to post some DDL, insert some rows...and post desired results.  This question is hard to follow (as is).

Comment: @granadaCoder I would be happy to answer any query..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database has these two tables: `User(UserID-PK,UserName,...)` and `Notification(NotificationID-PK,UserID,notification_sent,...)` then you could use this query to get for every user the following columns: `HasNotifications`(1,0) and `HasUnsentNotifications`(1,0) :

```
SELECT u.UserID,u.UserName,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(    
    SLEECT *
    FROM Notification n 
    WHERE u.UserID=n.UserID ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasNotifications,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(    
    SLEECT *
    FROM Notification n 
    WHERE u.UserID=n.UserID AND n.notification_sent=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasUnsentNotifications
FROM User n
WHERE n.UserID IN (3,10,...)
```

But, if you need a list with those users that doesn't have notifications plus those users that have unsent notifications then you could use another query:

```
SELECT u.UserID,u.UserName,
    CASE WHEN n.NotificationID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasNotifications,
    n.NotificationID,n.notication_detail
FROM User u LEFT OUTER JOIN Notification n ON u.UserID=n.UserID 
WHERE (n.notification_sent=0 -- Has unsent notifications
OR n.NotificationID IS NULL)
WHERE n.UserID IN (3,10,...)
```

**Edit 1 (SQL Server):**

If you don't know for how many user you have to run a query then you could use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @SelectedUsers TABLE(UserID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @SelectedUsers (UserID) VALUES (3);
...
INSERT @SelectedUsers (UserID) VALUES (10);

SELECT ...
FROM User n
WHERE n.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM @SelectedUsers)
```

or

```
DECLARE @SelectedUsers TABLE(UserID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @SelectedUsers (UserID) VALUES (3);
...
INSERT @SelectedUsers (UserID) VALUES (10);

SELECT u.UserID,
    CASE WHEN n.NotificationID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasNotifications,
    n.NotificationID,n.notication_detail
FROM @SelectedUsers u LEFT OUTER JOIN Notification n ON u.UserID=n.UserID 
WHERE (n.notification_sent=0 -- Has unsent notifications
OR n.NotificationID IS NULL)
```

Comment: there is nothing like hasNotification in my table.. secondly I dont want to make a join with user tables as it has too many rows..

Comment: In both cases, `HasNotifications` is an expression, isn't a column in `User` or `Notification` tables. Doesn't matter is `User` tables has many rows. How many rows ? 1,000,000 or maybe 100,000,000 ? Anyway, there is a predicate (`WHERE n.UserID IN (3,10,...)`) that should limit the users.

Comment: If I would know how many users I have to search, I would simply write a simple where for all in a for loop.. the IDs 3,10 are not sure on runtime..

Comment: @user1765876: See **[Edit 1]**